# shasum of a directory in macos

Tags: macos, shell-script, hashing

I'm writing a shell script that uses the `shasum` to check if the contents of a directory have changed.

On Linux and FreeBSD, the `shasum` have the same behavior when I do `shasum <directory>` however, on MacOS the `shasum` give me hashes **for files only**.

**FreeBSD**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
7f986e5e5289c59db1bba48df92ffe4707830aaa  CONTENTS/
```

**Linux**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
7f986e5e5289c59db1bba48df92ffe4707830aaa  CONTENTS/
```

**MacOS**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
shasum: CONTENTS/:
```

How could I calculate the hash of a directory in MacOS?

**TRY 1: Using TAR with pipes**

Tried to use but seems that this tar option doesn't work on MacOS.

```
tar cO CONTENTS/ | shasum
tar: Option -O is not permitted in mode -c
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  -
```

**TRY 2: Using FIND/EXEC**

It was consistent between MacOS and FreeBSD, but Linux returned a weird hash

```
find CONTENTS -type f -exec shasum {} \; | sort -k 2 | shasum
```

*Linux*

```
c2ddb9bc5f543e956f5cdcc76750cb78cc5f26f3
```

*FreeBSD*

```
3ac2a9d4e2fc5d2d2ec3c7f612e680990cc35824
```

*MacOS*

```
3ac2a9d4e2fc5d2d2ec3c7f612e680990cc35824
```

**OTHER FINDINGS ON TAR**

`tar` would be excellent as it "archives" a folder and then I could `shasum` it, however the order of how `tar` "walk" the folder structure is **not consistent across operating systems**. As some helpers mentioned in the comments that I should use the same version of `tar` in all systems.

Just an example, on system 1 I have this order:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:23 usr/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/aaa
```

and on system 2 I have the following order:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:23 usr/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/aaa
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/aaa
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/aaa
```

From a `tar` standpoint it if all good, but due to the order, the `shasum` produces a different hash.

**CONCLUSION**

`shasum` is consistent among Linux and BSDs to check an individual file hash, but, when it comes to directories the consistency happens only on MacOS and FreeBSD, perhaps due to how files are sorted.

If sorting is enforced using the `find` command, consistency is only obtained in FreeBSD and MacOS, however this method is time prohibitive as it takes a significant amount of time to calculate the hashes for every single file and then the whole structure hash.

Using `tar` to create a temporary file and then doing a `shasum` also found to be inconsistent between Linux and BSDs, perhaps because of difference in the archiving method.

I think the only way forward is to **redesign my solution**.

Comment: I don't think `shasum` is doing what you want it to do for you when you call it on a directory under Linux or FreeBSD. I just SSH'd into an Ubuntu 18.04 box, created a directory, shasum'd it, created a text file in it, and shasum'd the directory again, and the sum didn't change.

Comment: Do you need to do this **across** the three platforms, or just **within** the three platforms?

Comment: I need it to run it in any Linux distro, BSDs and MacOS. My preference is to not install anything. Homebrew is not an option. I will most likely redesign my script so that it runs with the stock system. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`mtree` is the tool you want.

Suppose:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ date > foo/date1; sleep 3
$ date > foo/date2; sleep 3
$ date > foo/date3
$ grep . foo/*
foo/date1:Wed Jul 24 16:11:32 PDT 2019
foo/date2:Wed Jul 24 16:11:35 PDT 2019
foo/date3:Wed Jul 24 16:11:38 PDT 2019
$ find . -ls
7318841   0 drwxr-xr-x    3 admin    staff     102 Jul 24 16:11 .
7318847   0 drwxr-xr-x    5 admin    staff     170 Jul 24 16:11 ./foo
7318849   8 -rw-r--r--    1 admin    staff      29 Jul 24 16:11 ./foo/date1
7318851   8 -rw-r--r--    1 admin    staff      29 Jul 24 16:11 ./foo/date2
7318853   8 -rw-r--r--    1 admin    staff      29 Jul 24 16:11 ./foo/date3
```

Create a reference manifest of directory `foo` and store it in `foo.mtree`:

```
$ mtree -c -K sha256digest -p foo > foo.mtree
```

Now go and mess with any file in that directory.

```
$ touch foo/date3
```

Run `mtree` again and pass it the manifest you created earlier, and `mtree` will tell you what
changed:

```
$ mtree -p foo < foo.mtree || echo fail
date3 changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:38 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:14:00 2019
fail

$ echo '$ date > foo/date2' >> bar
$ mtree -p foo < foo.mtree || echo fail
date2 changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:35 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:19:40 2019
        SHA-256 expected c76a568f08d98c2830f2fdfb42415c3ec15341b8741450d4bbd863f1d5c4c691 found ddcf8d07785bfe4d031a989339835dc3b8b44653019568dcee612c44fc8e2f70
date3 changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:38 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:14:00 2019
fail
```

Any files missing from `foo` or added since the manifest was created will also be reported:

```
$ mv foo/date1 foo/date4
$ mtree -p foo < foo.mtree || echo fail
. changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:38 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:21:38 2019
date2 changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:35 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:19:40 2019
        SHA-256 expected c76a568f08d98c2830f2fdfb42415c3ec15341b8741450d4bbd863f1d5c4c691 found ddcf8d07785bfe4d031a989339835dc3b8b44653019568dcee612c44fc8e2f70
date3 changed
        modification time expected Wed Jul 24 16:11:38 2019 found Wed Jul 24 16:14:00 2019
date4 extra
./date1 missing
fail
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, I will test this across Linux and BSDs and see if it will solve my problem. Not sure if mtree is available on Linux. Anyway..

Comment: It's super easy to build.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1389580/copy-directory-structure-only-at-year-end/1389998#1389998). @ttkdroid

Comment: As nice as mtree is, it wasn't useful for me because it also considers file metadata. If a file contents were exactly identical, but the file metadata changed (the file was re-built) between runs, it flagged it as a change.

Comment: @Joe You can choose which attributes to include or exclude. See the man page for `-k` and `-K` options. If all you want to check is content, then `-k cksum` or `-k sha256` might be the option flags you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) will do what (I think it is) you want.

Relevant points:

- It doesn't use SHA by default, but can be told to.
- It can be installed on MacOS via homebrew.
- By default it doesn't calculate a checksum for a single specified directory. It can be told to calculate checksums for all directories from a given starting point, as a way of finding "duplicate" directories below that point. But as a side effect, will also do exactly what you seem to be asking.
- It may be overkill for what you're looking for, and may take a while for you to figure out the best option flags to use, but is quite robust.
- Figuring out what flags to use might be tricky. Getting directory checksums is easy enough, but getting it to *not* do other things, can be tricky. (Although to be clear, it doesn't actually modify anything. At most, it generates a shell script, that you can manually run later, to modify things if desired. What it seems you need, is the JSON and/or CSV output files, which will give you the directory checksum you're looking for.)

I use rmlint in a bash script to find duplicate directories. Here is a command that will minimally do what you want, and as little else as possible:

`rmlint "base/dir/to/start/from" --see-symlinks --hidden --algorithm=sha256 --types=none,duplicatedirs --no-backup -o csv:log.csv`

Comment: Thanks Jim, I will take your solution in consideration. But I have to change a few things in my own solution either.