# Check if file exists

Tags: bash, unix, find, checksum

I have a folder with thousands (70G `folder/to/check/`) images that I, for each file want check if its already existing in another directory with thousands of thousands images (414G `folder/to/search/`).

This is the script I came up with, but its taking a very long time to run so I think the task could be optimized.

```
find folder/to/check/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk -F" " '{ print $1,$2 }' | while read -r p1 p2; do find folder/to/search/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep "^$p1" && echo "Found: $p1 $p2" || echo "Not found: $p1 $p2"; done > out.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea how to or could point me in the right direction how to optimize the script? My skills is very basic tho.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

- Compute md5 sum of each image in "to-check" folder, write it to a text file.
- Compute md5 sum of each image in "to-search" folder, append to 1st file.
- Sort this giant file to a new file.
- Use something like `uniq -c` to get a count of the number of times each line is duplicated.

If I got your command right (I might not), I think right now you're executing `md5sum` a total of X * Y times, but with the above, that's reduced to X + Y times.

Comment: Using a file size criteria first avoids computing (and performing  the corresponding I/O) the MD5 of 99.5% of the files (on my current "live" photo library, 9860 JPG, only 50 have a file of the same size).

Comment: Yeah you are right. Mine is unnecessary slow. Unfortunately I cannot concatenate the files as I need to know which files I need to move from folder/to/check/ into folder/to/search/ before deleting folder/to/check/

Answer (score 0):

`mtree` is a handy utility whenever you need to compare two file hierarchies looking for same/different timestamps or same/different MD5/SHA256 hashes.

Let's set up a simple test hierarchy:

```
$ mkdir -p folder/to/check
$ mkdir -p folder/to/search
$ for N in $(jot -w %03d 10); do touch `/image-$N.jpg; done
$ for N in $(jot -w %03d 10 2); do touch folder/to/search/image-$N.jpg; done
```

`folder/to/check` has files `image-001` through `-010`, while `folder/to/search` has `image-002` through `-011`.  All files are identical (zero bytes long), but have varying timestamps.

If you **only** want to check the MD5 hash (and the presence/absence of each file), then:

```
$ mtree -kmd5 -cp folder/to/check | mtree -p folder/to/search 
extra: image-011.jpg
./image-001.jpg missing
```

The `extra` line says that `image-011.jpg` was present in `folder/to/search` but wasn't required to be (since it isn't in `folder/to/check`), and the `missing` line says that `image-001.jpg` was found in the source folder (`folder/to/check`) but not in the target folder (`folder/to/search`).

If you want to check the timestamp in addition to the MD5 hash, then:

```
$ mtree -Kmd5 -cp folder/to/check | mtree -p folder/to/search 
.:      modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-010.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-008.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-006.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
extra: image-011.jpg
image-007.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-009.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-004.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-003.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-002.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-005.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
./image-001.jpg missing
```

That output still shows the same `extra` and `missing` lines, plus a number of files that are identical in MD5 hash, but have different timestamps.  Finally, if any of the files has a different MD5 hash than its counterpart, `mtree` will tell you which ones:

```
$ date > folder/to/search/image-007.jpg
$ mtree -Kmd5 -cp folder/to/check | mtree -p folder/to/search
.:      modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-010.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-008.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-006.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
extra: image-011.jpg
image-007.jpg: 
        size (0, 29)
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:25:05 2019)
        md5digest (0xd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e, 0x6fd624d18a8fe0c096b19ff858a2acf7)
image-009.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-004.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-003.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-002.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
image-005.jpg: 
        modification time (Mon Sep 30 16:16:15 2019, Mon Sep 30 16:16:24 2019)
./image-001.jpg missing
```

Comment: Wow. This sounds very promising! I'll give it a try tonight when I'll get back home, then I can answer if this is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: It seems I don't have mtree on my machine (Debian). How can I install it? And is there a way to ignore the depth/folder location of a file?

Comment: @Staplerz [This post](https://superuser.com/a/1389998/735568) has a rough outline of how to install mtree.  I'm not aware of any way to ignore the folder location of the files.

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities around to do this, but it you want to it yourself:

- Get the size in bytes of all the files, and make lists of all the files with the exact same size.
- For lists that have more than one element (not that many, especially among big files):

  - compute the MD5 of all elements of the list
  - check for duplicates

In essence this makes you compute the MD5 hash **once** and only for files that you cannot discriminate on size.

This of course assumes that you have no duplicates among the existing files or among the new files (but can easily be tweaked to check this too).